# best practice/jquery: filtering multiple json feeds for date

Tags: jquery, json, performance, google-calendar-api

I am loading multiple (30) json feeds (public google calendars). Now I would like to filter these against a set date/time to make an availability check. While I am sure I can hack something together I would like to keep the impact on the client as low as possible. So I'm looking for best practive ideas on these questions... thanks!

1. is there a way to combine my 30 json calls (and therefore the http requests) into one call without using a server side proxy?
2. to reduce requests and speed up the webiste in general i was thinking to write a php script that calls the feeds every 30 minutes, saves the relevant data to a mysql table from which i can in return access them when delivering the page (which uses a cms anyway) - is this advisable or should i rather call the json feeds and merge them serverside and then deliver to the client?
3. the google feed delivers dates in this format: "2015-11-13T01:00:00+01:00" ... to filter whether a date/time is inbetween two google dates would it be advisable to turn them into datetime integers before comparing? does this save ressources?
4. in general, is there a way to measure the speed of my different approaches to find out which is the fastest and uses the fewest resources?

thank you for your insights!

Comment: For 2nd point, usually depends on the how 'fresh' data needs to be, if the server serving the data has caching or not, if you have limited number of API calls available, etc... But generally when I do this, I save results locally on my server and serve that file to user. Added benefit is that I can set update timer to once every n time intervals and if the API provider for any reason is down, I still have at least some data to serve from my local copy.

Comment: Also to add, when for example I query Git API, client sends request to node on the backend, node sends request to Git API and response gets served directly back to client, because in this case I want to get all updates when ever user sends request to see data. When I query mostly static data which doesn't change often, client sends request to node on the backend, node checks when was last update on the local copy, if more then 30 minutes have passed node sends API call, get the result, writes it in local copy, serves local copy, if less then 30 minutes then serve local copy right away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a free-busy query (https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/freebusy/query) and have one request for all 30 calendars for the given timeslot you are interested in. The query will return busy blocks in the time period.

An example:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/freeBusy?key={YOUR_API_KEY}
{
 "timeMin": "2015-11-01T00:00:00Z",
 "timeMax": "2015-11-01T04:00:00Z",
 "items": [
  {
   "id": "en.ch#holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com"
  },
  {
   "id": "en.slovak#holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com"
  }
 ]
}
```